# find part of rtf file with bold or italic

Tags: database, formatting, applescript, rtf

new to stackoverflow so forgive me if I make any mistake.

I'm new to programming and scripting, although I have messed a little little bit with python and understand the basic of filemaker pro.

This is my problem: I have a full database that I built over the years. Database is just a way to say because, actually, it's a huge amount of rtf files with topics inside it. Now that I've built some real database I want to transfer my data from one to another. Just one table

The real problem is: in my old rtf days, I used to store my data in a easy to view manner, meaning that all my titles were bold/italic/underlined, and the text itself wasn't. So, I have aproximately 200 rtf files, each with 10-20 (sub)topics, waiting to be transfered to a two-columns table (title; content)

I would appreciate if anyone have a better idea than mine. My idea was to run a script that found the bold/italic text, copy it to my table field, find the not-bold, copy to the other field, etc. But I'm unable to find the answer to my simple question: how do I search for (and select) bold text?

I'd like to use applescript (is what I'm sort of comfortable with), but could use some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set boldText to attribute runs of text of document 1 whose font contains "Bold"
end tell
```